# Jquery form submit and JSON data type return

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using Jquery form plugin to send my form via ajax. The server side
php script processes the form data and returns a JSON string in the following
format:

```
{"error":true,"message":"The username or email already exists. Please try again."}
```

Here's the ajax to send the form:

```
$('#register_form').ajaxForm({ 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:    showResponse

        }); 
});
```

Then on my html page, I have the following script:

```
<script>
function showResponse(data){

if (data.error == true){
    //display the top error div
    if ($("#registration_error").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#registration_error").html(data.message);
        $("#registration_error").slideDown("slow");
    } 

}
else{
    alert('registration complete');

}


}
</script>
```

The error is displayed above the registration form in my HTML page. This
works in chrome and firefox. However, IE is wiping out the form and 
displaying a new page with just the JSON reply like so:

{"error":true,"message":"The username or email already exists. Please try again."}

I can't seem to figure out why IE is having problems with this. 
Please help.

Comment: Would you want to try returning false on the submit button click event after triggering the ajaxForm?

Comment: I tried it, and the same problem still exists. I really don't know what's going on with IE. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop the form from submitting before you're stating the ajaxForm

```
$('#register_form').submit(function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); });
```

Looks like the jquery was not able to successfully prevent the form from being submitted on IE. Which IE did you use anyways?

Comment: I'm using IE 8, thanks though, I'll give it a try and see what happens.